# Axios Promise in React calling Maximum Call Error

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm building a React App, and in it I am using Axios to pull in JSON data.
This is working, however, on receiving the data, I am getting the following error: 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'.

This really slows down the site and the error keeps repeating itself every time I set the state.

I've been banging my head up a wall for a few days with this one and really need some help with it!

Main Component with Axios: http://pastebin.com/mWJh2bpE

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to call `setState` without a callback? Something like this: `_this.setState({ data : mapResponse, formHTML: _this.buildFormHTML(mapResponse) })`.

Comment: The more I look at it, I think there is some kind of issue between my inputs and axion, for some reason on setting the state of the input, it's triggering the promise again.